# jQuery Datatable expands rows on document.ready

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

Hello all I would like to expand all the child rows and show them to the user. I tried this way but it is not expanding the rows

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        var table = $('#example').DataTable({
            "ajax": {
                "url": '@Url.Action("GetJson", "Home")',
                "dataSrc": function (d) {

                    g_dataFull = d.data;
                    var dataParent = []
                    $.each(d.data, function () {
                        if (this.Parent === "null") {
                            dataParent.push(this);
                        }
                    });

                    return dataParent;
                }
            },

            "columns": [
                {
                    "className": 'details-control',
                    "orderable": false,
                    "data": null,
                    "defaultContent": ''
                },
                { "data": "Name" },
                { "data": "Description" },
                { "data": "Work" },
                { "data": "Duration" },
                { "data": "StartDate" },
                { "data": "DueDate" },
                { "data": "CompletePercent" },
                { "data": "RemainingEffort" },
            ],
            "order": [[1, 'asc']]
        }).
        rows().every(function () {
            if (!this.child.isShown()) {
                // Open this row
                this.child(format(this.data())).show();
                $(this.node()).addClass('shown');
            }
        });
        });
```

I also tried this way but no luck, when I place the same code in a button event it is working as expected

```
table.rows().every(function () {
            if (!this.child.isShown()) {
                // Open this row
                this.child(format(this.data())).show();
                $(this.node()).addClass('shown');
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to put this property in dataTable.

`'display: $.fn.dataTable.Responsive.display.childRowImmediate,'`

You can check [My Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/gefamgtL/)